# Using list alias in WHERE or GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, alias

I'm writing a stored procedure containing SQL Select queries with some functions on some columns and a GROUP BY clause.
Obviously, I have to repeat these functions in the GROUP BY, which dramatically decreases code readability and increases redundancy.

So far, an alternative I have found was to use a derived query so I can access the alias names defined in the "second-level" query from the "top-level" query.
I was moderately happy with this workaround as it increases code complexity (and indentation) and I feel that I shouldn't have to use two queries when I can return all the data I want using a single one.

I've googled a bit and I found this page which returns the same tip about the subquery (+ one about creating a view but that's overkill in most cases).

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-use-a-select-list-alias-in-the-where-or-group-by-clause.html

I can't seriously believe that in 2010, there is no other way, especially with all the focus on code reusability and readability that has been going on for some years: would anyone have an elegant tip I never heard ever heard of (for SQL Server 2005/2008), or have an educated guess at why things should still be done that way in 2010?

Thanks.

Anonymous.

Comment: with regards to SQL, go with the code that builds the best execution plan and runs the fastest as a result, regardless of how "pretty" the indentation is or how many times you repeat trivial lines of code.  Many times going for a "pretty" query will drastically affect the speed and performance of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CTE`s (which can be nested and reused):

```
WITH    sub AS
        ( 
        SELECT  *, LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS FullName
        FROM    Employees 
        ),
        moresub AS
        (
        SELECT   *, Title + ' ' + FullName AS TitledName
        FROM     sub
        )
SELECT  FullName
FROM    moresub
WHERE   moresub.TitledName = 'Mr. Bertrand, Aaron'
UNION ALL
SELECT  FullName
FROM    moresub
WHERE   moresub.FullName = 'Doe, John'
```

**Update:**

Seems I misunderstood your question.

In `MySQL`, you can use the `SELECT` list aliases in `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses:

```
SELECT  id + 1 AS myalias
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS id
        ) q
GROUP BY
        myalias
HAVING  myalias <= 3
ORDER BY
        myalias DESC
```

, but `MySQL` is known for poor handling of the nested queries, so this ability is vital for performance.

Most probably that the other systems (which handle the nested queries and the `CTE`s quite well) just decided that they have more important things to implement.

Comment: If the derived table solution already tripped OP up, this most likely will to.